# input center, label above and to the left

Tags: html, css, web, label, text-align

I'm doing homework where I have to recreate a page using HTML and CSS. One side of the page displays the following:

[image: Page 1]

I need the input in the center of the `div` and the label, above and to the left of the input.

For now I have this:

```
<div id="completarcampos">

                <label id="lbltelefono" for="campotelefono">Numero de telefono:</label></br>
                <input type="text" id="campotelefono"/></br>

                <label id="lblcontraseña" for="campocontraseña">contraseña:</label></br>
                <input type="text" id="campotelefono"/></br></br>

                <a href="http://www.w3schools.com"><img id="ingresar" src="./imagenes/boton.png" alt="ingresar"/></a></br></br>

            </div>
```

and this

```
input
    {width:200px;}  

completarcampos
    {border: 2px solid #BCBCBC;
    text-align:center;
    background: linear-gradient(#eeeeee, #ffffff);}
```

and it looks like this:

[image: Current Result]

How could I have the labels to line up as they are but to the left of the input?

Comment: Please add the images to the question, especially since the links give a 403 - Forbidden.

Comment: Since this is your homework, you may not get the exact answer here, it's always better to figure it out yourself when you can. However, you want to look at CSS classes, and their margin or padding attributes, to get an idea of how to move stuff around the page.

Comment: @ChrisHinton It is an easy fix however, I have seen veterans of html and css miss things like this, you should have just taken a second to look over his code, simple syntax error, nothing to do with your comment.

Comment: I try putting the picture but I came out something about the reputation.

Comment: @GRreanimation is my answer or fiddle what you are looking for?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which of the two images is the correct one?

Comment: the first image is the correct, the second It's what I did

Comment: @GRreanimation I added a second answer that solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok add a div container around the input and the label and then float the label left like this:   https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/f4fhn0wn/3/

```
<div id="completarcampos">
                <div class="container">
                <label id="lbltelefono" for="campotelefono">Numero de telefono:</label></br>
                <input type="text" id="campotelefono"/></br>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                <label id="lblcontraseña" for="campocontraseña">contraseña:</label></br>
                <input type="text" id="campotelefono"/></br></br>
                </div>

                <a href="http://www.w3schools.com"><img id="ingresar" src="./imagenes/boton.png" alt="ingresar"/></a></br></br>
</div>
```

Comment: is what I wanted, thanks, I'll get to see it to understand :)

Comment: @GRreanimation Don't worry about all the negative comments below your post, for a first time "asker" you did better than most.